# PreparedStatement with parameterised where clause in select statement throwing Exception

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am getting exception as SQLException showing there is a something wrong in the syntax and check the manual for same.

My java code is as follows.

```
PreparedStatement pst;
String sql ="SELECT * FROM patient.medicine where _id=?";
pst = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.setInt(1, 1);
ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery(sql);
```

If I execute this by appending the variable holding a value for id, everything works fine.

```
*SELECT * FROM patient.medicine where _name=?*
Oct 19, 2013 11:15:46 AM com.seed.entity.Patient getData
SEVERE: null
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in   your 

  SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the 
  right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2728)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2678)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1612)
at com.seed.entity.Patient.getData(Patient.java:257)
at com.seed.entity.Patient.main(Patient.java:360)
```

Comment: Sorry! Nothing works. May be you have to do some different to programming.

Comment: Now I have changed the query but it still not replacing ? with the value

Comment: patient is the name of my database and it also have patient table and medicine table inside and the select query works without any errors without prepared statement.

Comment: See the update in my answer.

Comment: why negative marking I didn't understood. Paul has given the right answer to the question.

Comment: +1... Because you defend my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is one error in you code:

```
PreparedStatement pst;
String sql ="SELECT * FROM patient.patient P WHERE P._ID = ?";
pst = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setInt(1, 1);
ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery(); // without arguments
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL should just be

```
SELECT * FROM patient WHERE patient._ID = ?
```

The table name `patient.patient` seems incorrect since the column is referred to as `patient._ID`

Comment: What's the database type of `_ID` column? If it's text you need to use `setString()` instead.

Comment: No its numerical data only int datatype of MySQL

Comment: Is `patient.medicine` really your table name? That's unusual. Can you do `select * from patient.medicine` without errors?

Comment: patient is the name of my database and it also have patient table and medicine table inside and the select query works without any errors

Answer (score 0):

change this `String sql = "SELECT * FROM patient.patient WHERE patient._ID=?";`

to `String sql = "SELECT * FROM patient WHERE patient._ID=?";`

Comment: yeah same exception as it is not replacing the ? with the value specified in the `setInt()` method.

Comment: @Chaitanya post the stacktrace

Comment: @Chaitanya what is your table name?

Comment: My Stack trace is added in the question now

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39542/discussion-between-chaitanya-and-javabeginner)

Comment: @Chaitanya what is your table name?